# How to access a file embedded as a resource in a nuget package in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, swagger

I have a class project which I want to use as a base class for my API, and this base class should contain my own modified version of swagger-ui.js

If I build my project, in the bin\debug\netcoreapp2.0 folder I get the following files:
 MyServiceCommon.dll
 MyServiceCommon.deps.json
 \swagger-ui\swagger-ui.js

However when this project is built into a nuget package, in my api project when I reference it, I will only see 
MyServiceCommon.dll in the bin\debug folder

How can I gain access to the \swagger-ui\swagger-ui.js file in this referencing project?

Comment: Have you considered embedding the resource into the DLL itself?

Comment: Yes, but not sure how to extract it

Comment: You'd use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` - that hasn't changed for .NET Core.